# What is the value of $a+b$ Satisfies these two equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $a,b\in \mathbb R$ Such that :
$$\cases{a^3-3a^2+5a-17=0 \\ b^3-3b^2+5b+11=0}$$

Find the value of $a+b$

I’ve tried to add the two equation and factoring $a+b$ but it didn’t help me.
I think that letting $f(x)=x^3-3x^2+5x-17$ And $g(x)=b^3-3x^2+5x+11$ Could help . **claim :**$a+b=2$

Comment: No there is no typos

Comment: Did you really check for typos?  If you use $a^3-3b^2+5b-17=0$ for the first equation, you get a real solution that sums to $2$.  [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a%5E3-3b%5E2%2B5b-17%3D0%2C+b%5E3-3a%5E2%2B5a%2B11%3D0+over+the+reals)

Comment: You can see the original picture @lulu

Comment: That's not what you wrote, however.  You got the second equation badly wrong.

Comment: "There’s no typos : "  Uh... yes there are.  And it's the *exact* typo lulu predicted.  That a $-3b^2$.  *not* $-3a^2$.

Comment: The picture shows that you have misstated the problem.

Comment: @fleablood  Bizarrely, it isn't.  It's a different typo that also has a solution that sums to $2$

Comment: Oh,  you are right.

Comment: I didn’t see the typo....sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a=c+1, b=d+1$

Then the equations becomes

$$c^3+2c-14=0$$

$$d^3+2d+14=0$$

Add them up,

$$c^3+d^3+2c+2d=0\iff (c+d)(c^2-cd+d^2)+2(c+d)=0\\(c+d)(c^2-cd+d^2+2)=0$$

Since $c^2-cd+d^2+2$ clearly $>0$ we know $c+d=0$ so $a+b=2$

Comment: So the claim was right ?

Comment: Yes it was right in the original version. I was doing the math in the typo version and posted a comment based on that. I have already deleted the comment after seeing the update, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: not problem, i just want to know if it exists a method of solving this problem using derivatives or generally calculus ?

Comment: Probably no, based on the fact that if the two $14$ does not cancel out then there won't be a nice answer to the problem. That is, the nice answer really depended on the two numbers $-17$ and $11$ but when you take derivative those numbers become zero.

Comment: why did you put this change of variables? why Exactly $a=c+1$?

Comment: So that the square powered term can be cancelled out. This is the standard trick used to derive the general cubic formula as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote $a+b = x$, and substitute $b = x - a$ in the second equation

\begin{cases}
a^3-3a^2 + 5a - 17=0 \\
(x-a)^3 - 3(x-a)^2 + 5(x-a) + 11 = 0
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
a^3-3a^2 + 5a - 17=0 \\
-a^3 + 3 a^2 x - 3 a^2 - 3 a x^2 + 6 a x - 5 a + x^3 - 3 x^2 + 5 x + 11 = 0
\end{cases}

Add the first equation to the second equation:
\begin{cases}
a^3-3a^2 + 5a - 17=0 \\
3 a^2 x - 6 a^2 - 3 a x^2 + 6 a x + x^3 - 3 x^2 + 5 x - 6 = 0
\end{cases}

Notice that the second equation may be rewritten as:
$$x(3a^2-3ax+x^2-x+3) - 2(3a^2-3ax+x^2-x+3) = 0$$
$$(x-2)(3a^2-3ax+x^2-x+3) = 0$$

We therefore get that $a+b = x = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the arithmetic mean of two expressions
$$f(x)=x^3-3x^2+5x-3$$

Then $f(x)=(x-1)((x-1)^2+2)$ has only root at $x=1$. This means graph of $f(x)$ is symmetric about the point $(1,0)$. It increases monotonically like graph of $y=x^3$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Now $a,b$ are such that $f(a)=14$, $f(b)=-14$. So $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ are symmetrically located about $(1,0)$. Hence $$\frac{a+b}{2}=1 \quad ; \quad \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}=0$$